# Is the space of affine continuous functions a Baire space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be a compact convex set in q linear normed space. Let $A(\Omega)$ be the space of affine continuous real-valued functions. My question is whether the space $A(\Omega)$ is a Baire space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under what topology?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker under compact-open topology.

Comment: Since $\ \Omega\ $ is compact, doesn't mean the uniform topology (i.e. of the uniform convergence)?

Comment: @WlodAA Yes, exactly.

Comment: $A(\Omega)$ is a complete metric space w.r. to the uniform metrics hence it is a Baire space (in a strong sense): the intersection of a countable number of open dense subsets is dense.

Comment: @WlodAA How to show $A(\Omega)$ is a complete metric space?

Comment: Completeness of $A(\Omega)$ seems to be a nice but simple and straightforward exercise. One can apply the involved definitions, and not much more, that's all.